# mysql. Stored Procedure Error 1328

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, informix

This is really baffling me. I am converting a simple procedure from informix into mysql. What it basically does is tell me what the next event is from an event table and a calendar table. In informix the procedure is simple.

```
FOREACH
SELECT  date,weekno,event
INTO    l_date,l_week,l_event
FROM    event,calendar
WHERE   dayno = dayno
AND     date = l_today
AND     start >= l_now
UNION
SELECT  date,weekno,event
FROM    event,calendar
WHERE   dayno = dayno
AND     date > l_today
UNION
SELECT  TODAY,9999,9999
FROM    event,calendar
WHERE   dayno   = dayno
AND     event = (SELECT MAX(event) FROM event)
ORDER BY 3

if l_event = 9999 then <error> end if;
EXIT FOREACH
END FOREACH
```

So basically the query finds the next event and returns it. l_today and l_event are parameters that are passed. So on to the mysql version.

```
looper: BEGIN
    DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT CONCAT("SELECT date, weekno, event FROM event INNER JOIN calendar ON dayno = dayno",
                " WHERE date = '", lv_today ,"' AND start >= '", lv_time ,"'",
                " UNION SELECT date, weekno, event FROM event INNER JOIN calendar ON dayno = dayno WHERE date > '", lv_today ,"'",
                " UNION SELECT DATE(NOW()) AS date, 9999 AS weekno, 9999 AS event FROM event INNER JOIN calendar ON dayno = dayno",
                " WHERE (SELECT MAX(event) FROM event) ORDER BY event ");

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

    OPEN curs1;
    loop1: LOOP
        FETCH curs1 INTO ldate, lweek, levent;
        SELECT ldate, lweek, levent;
        LEAVE looper;
    END LOOP loop1;
END;
```

I haven't checked that the rest of the methodology works because I get this error:

> 1328. Incorrect number of FETCH variables.

Does this mean that I have declare a different variable for each of the query returns? I am new to mysql. If this is the case what would be the best way to solve this conundrum? I have also changed to column and table names.

Many thanks

Comment: There is a difference between `SELECT CONCAT('SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL');` and `SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL;`, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hfZtBUpJ9779ptmgRGQriV/1).

Comment: You have `SELECT ldate, lweek, levent;` in the loop.  Where are those selected values stored? Or what is that doing?  It seems most peculiar to me from the Informix viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

```
looper: BEGIN
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT eve_date, dia_weekno, eve_event 
FROM game_event 
INNER JOIN stan_calendar ON eve_abs_dayno = dia_abs_dayno
WHERE eve_date = lv_today
AND eve_start >= lv_time
UNION 
SELECT eve_date, dia_weekno, eve_event 
FROM game_event 
INNER JOIN stan_calendar ON eve_abs_dayno = dia_abs_dayno 
WHERE eve_date > lv_today
UNION SELECT DATE(NOW()) AS eve_date, 9999 AS dia_weekno, 9999 AS eve_event 
FROM game_event 
INNER JOIN stan_calendar ON eve_abs_dayno = dia_abs_dayno
WHERE (SELECT MAX(eve_event) FROM game_event) ORDER BY eve_event;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

OPEN curs1;

curs_loop: LOOP
    FETCH curs1 INTO lv_date, lv_week, lv_event;

    SELECT lv_date, lv_week, lv_event;
    LEAVE looper;

    CLOSE curs1;
END LOOP curs_loop;
```

Thank you for answering my question, I have put it back to how I thought it was... and it now works. Here is the loop in full.

Comment: This appears to be commentary on the question, and as such should be edited into the question, not presented as an answer.  You can edit your own question.  Don't destroy anything that an answer hinges on — but I'm not sure that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fetch.html *The number of columns retrieved by the SELECT statement must match the number of output variables specified in the FETCH statement* so yes but in fact you are only selecting 1 concatenated string - I think your first problem is with the select syntax which doesn't need the concat, the brackets or the quotes (unless you are trying to create a prepared statement for some reason - and even if you were I doubt if the code would be correct)

Simple Cursor

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EC;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `EC`(
    IN `inemp_no` varchar(255)

)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
LOOPER:begin
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
declare ename varchar(20);
declare esalary int default 0;
declare emp_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT last_name,salary FROM employees where emp_no= inemp_no ;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

open emp_cursor;
read_loop: loop
        fetch emp_cursor into ename,esalary;
        if done then leave read_loop; end if;
        insert into debug_table (msg) values(concat('employee:',ename,' earns:',esalary));
end loop;
close emp_cursor;
end $$

DELIMITER ;



MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table debug_table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> call ec(2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from debug_table;
+----+--------------------------+------+
| id | msg                      | MSG2 |
+----+--------------------------+------+
|  1 | employee:BBB earns:39500 | NULL |
+----+--------------------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. The reason for the concat is the procedure was always returning 9999. So, I was assuming that the parameters being passed into the query for the loop were not working correctly, as if I do the same query outside of the procedure I get another answer. Because the query is in a loop it seems that this need to be prepared in a specific way, it is this that I am trying to get my head around as the syntax is completely different to that of which I am used to.

Comment: Your procedure is a mess. The label looper: does nothing at all it's just a label. The begin..end block is required if you execute want to execute  many statements in your procedure. The leave looper statement is incorrect since the loop you want to leave is the curs_loop. If you are using variables (lv_date, lv_week, lv_event) then you must declare them immediately after the begin statetement.  I have added a simple procedure to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, This was just a snippet of a larger procedure. There is also a call to another procedure above this, but that was working fine. The outside loop "looper" is the loop that I wanted to exit from, sorry for the confusion, and this worked fine to. My real issue was the preparation of the SQL, and it does look a right mess.